# My wx.OnPaint() function is not called constantly in the wx main loop

Tags: python, wxpython, pyopengl

I working on a project using OpenGL and wxPython to make a navigatable 3D user interface.
However, the `OnPaint()` function doesn't seem to be called continuously in the main loop. That makes my interface not being updated constantly. The function is only called I drag around the window. For example: when I press an arrow key, the object in the window only moves when I drag around the window.

I boiled my code down to these lines of codes. Can anyone help me make the `OnPaint()` function called constantly in print a bunch of "HI" without the need to drag around the window?

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

```py
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame()
        frame.Show()
        return True
```

```py
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = (1000, 700)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title ="wx", size=self.size)
        self.canvas = MyCanvas(self)
```

```py
class MyCanvas(GLCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        GLCanvas.__init__(self, parent, -1, size=(1000, 700))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        print("HI")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `wx.Window` like `wx.Frame` or `GLCanvas`can be forced to be repainted by [`.Refresh()`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.Refresh).
e.g. You can use the [`wx.IdleEvent`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.IdleEvent.html) to triggers the canvas to be refreshed continuously.

```py
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = (1000, 700)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title ="wx", size=self.size)
        self.canvas = MyCanvas(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, self.OnIdle)

    def OnIdle(self, event):
        self.Refresh()         # refresh self and all its children
        #self.canvas.Refresh() # refresh self.canvas
```